# How to change the color of Bootstrap links

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using twitter bootstrap and I have some code like this:

```
<%= link_to "Create", new_something_path %>
```

which renders the text in a light blue color, highlighting it as a link.

How would I reference that element to change it via css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CSS class or id to a `link_to` by setting it in the `html_options` hash, which is the last parameter of the `link_to` helper.

For example, using Ruby 1.9 hash syntax (convert to `:key => 'value'` if using Ruby 1.8):

Just the CSS selector `.new-something-class`:

`<%= link_to "Create", new_something_path, class: 'new-something-class' %>`

or for a link with with the CSS selectors `#new-something-id` and `.new-something-class`:

`<%= link_to "Create", new_something_path, class: 'new-something-class', id: 'new-something-id' %>`

You could then reference this element in your `.css` file(s) as usual.

Answer (score 3):

Give the link a class name

```
<%= link_to 'Create', new_something_path , :class => "newsomething"%>
```

add the following to your CSS.SCSS file

```
 a.newsomething{
      color: #000;
      &:hover {
         color: #000;
       }
     }
```

Comment: You are using LESS syntax here.

Answer (score -1):

If you have twitter bootstrap installed:

```
<%= link_to 'Create', new_something_path , :class => "btn btn-primary some-class"%>
```

css

```
.some-class{
   color: black;
   ....    
}
```

Comment: This would add both the `btn` and the `btn-primary` stylings to the link, not enable him to reference it via CSS.

Comment: ok so there isn't an element like .navbar where you can access it, okies cool, you have to do it manually, thanks everyone! all upvoted, Andy